Changing font colour in XLSX file preserving all other style features using openxlsx2
Necessary preamble that will explain my clumsy syntax below: I am a novice with R and having developed in Python for ages I find the R syntax to be unclear form a OOP perspective (i.e. hard to find out attributes and methods of an object).
I have a bunch of Excel workbooks (.xlsx) that are routinely created with openxlsx and contain a lot of detailed styling on specific cell ranges.
My issue with the outputs is that I would like the font colour to be set to Automatic, but I read that openxlsx doesn't handle this. It looks like openxlsx2 can handle automatic font colour but the syntax is markedly different than for openxlsx and recoding all the existing scripts to use openxlsx2 would require some significant time investment. Doable but a lot of work.
I though a shortcut would be to use openxlsx2 after all files have been created through the usual openxlsx, opening each workbook and using wb_add_font on each non-empty cell.
My problem with this approach is that the function wb_add_font() will overwrite the existing cell style with the defaults. I would like only change the color argument and leave the rest unchanged.
What I wantedto do is to go through all cells, get their style  object and then apply wb_add_font() passing the attributes of the current style object as parameters, except for color, which I would set to wb_color(auto = 1).
But I stumbled into the problem that I don't know how to get the various style attributes from the style object I obtain through wb_get_cell_style().
The following pseudo code hopefully illustrates my original idea
# load the workbook
w <- wb_load("openxlsx_output.xlsx")

# do this for a single cell but can be easily fone in a loop
sheet_name <- "Sheet1"
cell_ref <- "A1"

# get current style in cell
current_style <- wb_get_cell_style(w, sheet = sheet_name, dims = cell_ref)

# change the color
# the syntax within brackets is what I am missing
wb_add_font(w, font_name = [current_style.font_name], ..., font_size = [current_style.font_size], color = wb_color(auto = 1))


If I drop any of the arguments in wb_add_font(), they will be set to the default, overwriting the previous formatting.
I have also tried playing with wb_set_base_font() but had no luck either way.

In ooxml the fonts are an independent xml string that is used via index reference in the cell style. In openxlsx2 the font is probably set with a default value instead of loading the previous font values. But it should be possible to load the previous values. You should be able to see the xml strings in wb$sytles_mgr$styles$font. I’ll try to come up with something

A first draft is here
